# How can I optimize this CSS code for Android & IOS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I have a test web app, trying different CSS solutions. I used the below CSS code as a background animation in my Ionic project.
Unfortunately, the code on Android stutters quite badly, and the low fps makes other functions in my app unusable & unstable. Please also find the original code link below.

Original code:
https://codepen.io/noahblon/pen/GKflw

I tried optimizing the code as per below to use hardware acceleration in app.

HTML Code

```
<div class="scene">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="wall wall-right"></div>
        <div class="wall wall-left"></div>   
        <div class="wall wall-top"></div>
        <div class="wall wall-bottom"></div> 
        <div class="wall wall-back"></div>    
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="wall wall-right"></div>
        <div class="wall wall-left"></div>   
        <div class="wall wall-top"></div>
        <div class="wall wall-bottom"></div>   
        <div class="wall wall-back"></div>    
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS Code:
Picture is locally stored as asset & is 800x400, 100KB.

```
.wall {
    background-image: url('../assets/imgs/4.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    //pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
  }


  .scene {
    //  left: 50%; top: 50%;
    left: 50%; top: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    perspective: 5px;
   // perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -10;

  }

  .wrap {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    left: -500px;
    top: -500px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-animation: move 350s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  .wrap:nth-child(2){
    -webkit-animation: move 350s infinite linear;
    animation-delay: 6s;
  }

  .wall{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    //animation: fade 350s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: fade 350s infinite linear;



    // -webkit-animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
    // animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;


    animation-delay: 0;
  }

  .wrap:nth-child(2) .wall {
    animation-delay: 6s;
  }

  .wall-right {
    transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg) translate3d(0,0,500px);
  }

  .wall-left {
    transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg) translate3d(0,0,500px);
  }

  .wall-top {
    transform: rotate3d(1,0,0,90deg) translate3d(0,0,500px);
  }

  .wall-bottom {
    transform: rotate3d(1,0,0,-90deg) translate3d(0,0,500px);
  }

  .wall-back {
    transform: rotate3d(1,0,0,180deg) translate3d(0,0,500px);
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes move {
    0%{
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,-500px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,500px) rotate(0deg);
    }
  }

  @keyframes move {
    0%{
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,-500px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,500px) rotate(0deg);
    }
  }


  @-webkit-keyframes fade {
    0%{
      opacity: 0;
    }
    25% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    75% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100%{
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }

  @keyframes fade {
    0%{
      opacity: 0;
    }
    25% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    75% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100%{
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

I am seeking a solution in optimizing the link provided or further using my edited code.
How would you optimize this animation for phone?

Comment: Try converting the image to webp for chrome and png for everything else that doesn't support webp. Also minify your CSS. There are free online tools that do it. See if that helps. 350s seems pretty long for an animation though, I've no idea if that's what could be contributing to the low performance. Try dropping it to 2s and see if that changes the performance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment.

Unfortunately the above solution does not work. I tried it with different pic formats, but that didn't change the performance here. With the animation reduced from 350 to 2 I realized that it does impact performance - while this affects my foreground elements to show more properly (with 350, a lot of elements won't even show when ngif set to true).
Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure, I can't replicate your issue. The codepen you posted runs seamlessly on my phone (OnePlus 3, Oreo, Chrome). Probably try creating a .gif of the animation and loading that instead?